# Rails 3, Action Mailer, attachments, form_for, email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, email-attachments

How could I attach a file to mail using form_for?  So far it gives me an error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#create

NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "file_field", "name", "text_field", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

This is what I came up with.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "example@gmail.com"

    def registration_confirmation(user)
      @user = user
         unless user[:file_field].nil?
           file=user[:file_field]
           attachments[file.original_filename] = File.open(file.path, 'rb'){|f| f.read}
         end
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

View

```
  <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :file_field %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :file_field %>
</div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Create action

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
    redirect_to @user
  else
   render action: "new" 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hot topic on stackoverflow, be sure to check out the other threads. They're really indepth, and should solve your problem.

E.g: [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625980/1792207), [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314127/1792207), [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177061/1792207)

If this doesn't turn out, come back and we'll be sure to fire up another mail-attachment thread.